# How to create slider of sets of pictures

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Look at this picture:

[image]
<sub>(source: [20script.ir](http://up.20script.ir/file/35b5-photo-2016-07-19-01-01-05.png))</sub>

I want to make squares like squares pointed in the picture to switch between sets of my pictures. every set contains 6 images, please describe the easiest way to do that. no problem if you use JQuery or Angular JS or pure javascript... Thank you.
Update: If you need it, This is my html code: ( I know it doesn't works because I don't know how to do that...)

```
<?php require ('functions.php');mob_check(); ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="fa-IR" data-ng-app="engineers" data-ng-controller="engineers_controller">
    <!-- Website design by Mohsen_Nirouzad -->

    <head>
        <script src="assets/js/angular.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Adding meta information -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="author" content="Mohsen Nirouzad - http://AproZ.ir">
        <!-- defining stylesheets DO NOT delete the bellow codes if you don't have enough knowledge of web design -->
        <!-- I used w3data.min.js for javascript templating engine so you've to change the bellow information in script tag -->
        <meta name="application-name" content="Sarabon website">
        <meta name="description" content="{{description}}">
        <meta name="keywords" content="{{keywords}}">
        <meta name="publisher" content="{{publisher}}">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>{{page_title}}</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/app.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/w3rtl.min.css">
        <script src="assets/js/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div data-ng-include="'variables/sidenav.html'"></div>
        <div style="margin-right:25%" class="w3-row">
            <div class="w3-col s6 w3-margin-right">
                <div data-ng-include="'variables/logo1.html'"></div>
                <div id="engineers_text" style="margin-top:50px;width:300px;">
                    <div>
                        <p id="activetext"></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="pull-left">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="changer1"><i id="font1"></i></a>
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="changer2"><i id="font2"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div style="width:300px;" class="w3-margin-top">
                    <div id="engineers_images" class="w3-row-padding">
                        <i class="fa fa-3x fa-file-image-o w3-col m4"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-3x fa-file-image-o w3-col m4"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-3x fa-file-image-o w3-col m4"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div id="engineers_images_two" class="w3-row-padding">
                        <i class="fa fa-3x fa-file-image-o w3-col m4"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-3x fa-file-image-o w3-col m4"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-3x fa-file-image-o w3-col m4"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="pull-left">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" hreflang="fa-IR" data-ng-click="change_image_1"><i data-ng-class="image_1"></i></a>
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" hreflang="fa-IR" data-ng-click="change_image_2"><i data-ng-class="image_1"></i></a>
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" hreflang="fa-IR" data-ng-click="change_image_3"><i data-ng-class="image_1"></i></a>
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" hreflang="fa-IR" data-ng-click="change_image_4"><i data-ng-class="image_1"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="w3-rest" style="margin-top:100px">
                <img alt="{{image_alt}}" title="{{image_title}}" src="{{image_src}}" class="w3-hover-opacity w3-card-2 w3-hover-shadow w3-round w3-padding fa-border">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left"></i></a>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="fa fa-close pull-left"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div data-ng-include="'variables/footer.html'"></div>


        <script>
            $(function () {
                var text1 = 'لورم ایپسوم دالر سیت آمت...لورم ایپسوم دالر سیت آمت...لورم ایپسوم دالر سیت آمت...لورم ایپسوم دالر سیت آمت...لورم ایپسوم دالر سیت آمت...لورم ایپسوم دالر سیت آمت...لورم ایپسوم دالر سیت آمت...لورم ایپسوم دالر سیت آمت...لورم ایپسوم دالر سیت آمت...لورم ایپسوم دالر سیت آمت...لورم ایپسوم دالر سیت آمت...لورم ایپسوم دالر سیت آمت...لورم ایپسوم دالر سیت آمت...لورم ایپسوم دالر سیت آمت...';
                var text2 = 'Lorem Ipsum Dolor sit Amet...Lorem Ipsum Dolor sit Amet...Lorem Ipsum Dolor sit Amet...Lorem Ipsum Dolor sit Amet...Lorem Ipsum Dolor sit Amet...Lorem Ipsum Dolor sit Amet...Lorem Ipsum Dolor sit Amet...Lorem Ipsum Dolor sit Amet...';
                var font_class1=
                $('#activetext').text(text1);
                $('a#changer1').click(function () {
                    $('#activetext').text(text1);
                    $('#font1').addClass('fa fa-square');
                    $('#font2').addClass('fa fa-square-o');
                });
                $('a#changer2').click(function () {
                    $('#activetext').text(text2);
                    $('#font2').addClass('fa fa-square');
                    $('#font1').addClass('fa fa-square-o');
                });
            });
            // Coded by Mohsen_Nirouzad
            // Start AngularJS Application
            var application = angular.module('engineers', []);
            // Set controller
            application.controller('engineers_controller', function ($scope) {
                // Seting page meta information
                $scope.description = 'Some Description',
                    $scope.keywords = 'key1,key2,key3',
                    $scope.application_name = 'Sarabon',
                    $scope.googleplus_url = '#',
                    $scope.page_title = 'مهندسین مشاور سرابن',                 
            });
        </script>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: I added my page code, ofcourse the page's incomplete and doesn't work properly. that's why I opened this question

Comment: No body could help me?